# Extract latest entry for each currency type from table

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

Solution required on Microsoft SQL Server.

Here is a example of a table I have:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Currency Code | Starting Date           | Exchange Rate Amount    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| CZK           | 2014-09-10 00:00:00.000 | 27.64000000000000000000 |
| EUR           | 2015-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 1.17570000000000000000  |
| CZK           | 2015-07-30 00:00:00.000 | 28.29840000000000000000 |
| PLN           | 2015-06-16 00:00:00.000 | 5.35640000000000000000  |
| EUR           | 2016-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 1.17090000000000000000  |
| PLN           | 2015-07-30 00:00:00.000 | 5.49070000000000000000  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to return the last entry for each [Currency Code] in a single table like so:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Currency Code | Starting Date           | Exchange Rate Amount    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| CZK           | 2015-07-30 00:00:00.000 | 28.29840000000000000000 |
| EUR           | 2016-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 1.17090000000000000000  |
| PLN           | 2015-07-30 00:00:00.000 | 5.49070000000000000000  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can do it individually like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Currency Code] AS Currency, CONVERT(varchar, [Starting Date], 103) AS Date, CAST([Exchange Rate Amount] AS DECIMAL(8,3)) AS Rate
FROM myTable
WHERE [Currency Code] = 'EUR'
ORDER BY [Starting Date] DESC
```

This returns the following:

```
---------------------------------
| Currency | Date       | Rate  |
---------------------------------
| EUR      | 01/09/2016 | 1.171 |
---------------------------------
```

However, I would like the last entry for each currency listed in a single table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to do this, with something like this:

```
select [Currency Code], [Starting Date], [Exchange Rate Amount]
from (
  select *, 
  row_number() over (
       partition by [Currency Code] 
       order by [Starting Date] desc
    ) as RN
  From myTable
) X where RN = 1;
```

The row number will number the rows per currency (that's what `partition by` does) starting from the newest, and then the outer `select` will just take the first for each currency.

Comment: Can the results be pivoted?

Comment: Certainly the results can be pivoted; this query could be moved into either a subquery or a CTE, which can then be the subject of a PIVOT query.